# Select most different observations

Tags: sample, histogram

I have a polar chart representing eight dimensional observations as 'rings' around the center. Furthermore, I am limited to Excel for graphing purposes, which means I can only display 255 series at once. My goal is for illustrative purposes only - it will be printed, so details will get lost anyways.

I would like to maximize the information content in the graph. So, given the 255 series limit, how should I select the observations to show? Is there some kind of measure to determine the amount of added information to the data, which is not affected by their order, to then drop those with the least info, until only 255 remain?

I appreciate the help!